# get another value when onfocus and call tokeninput

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using token input by James smith, I have a problem while getting value with on focus even because of I call token input at the same time. I need that value to get query and return result of query as the token list.

```html
 loadTokenInput2('txtunit',params,'Kode Unit', 60)
```

Comment: Where is your `focus`event, this one line means nothing so no help can be provided from this.

Comment: Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

i called token input with this function :

```
function loadTokenInput2(objtext,url,hinttext,widthtoken)
{
    if(!hinttext){hinttext="Type key in this text box";}
    if(!widthtoken){widthtoken=400;}
        $('#'+objtext).tokenInput(url,
        {
            tokenLimit :1,hintText: hinttext,tokenwidth:widthtoken,
            propertyToSearch: "id",
            resultsFormatter:function(item)
            {
                return "<li>" + "<div style='display: inline-block;'><table><tr><td><div class='id'>" + item.id + "</div></td><td><div class='name'>" + item.name + "</div></td></tr></table></div></li>" },
                tokenFormatter: function(item) { return "<li><p>" + item.id + "</p></li>"}
            });

    }
```

i make input text as below :

```
<input type=\"text\" id=\"txtlocation\" style=\"width:60px;\" onFocus=\"loadTokenInput2('txtlocation',$url,'Kode Location',60)\" onchange=\"$eventchange\" />
```

with `$eventchange` below:

```
  $eventchange="$('#txtunit').focus(function(){";
  $eventchange.="    var params='index.php?ajax=1&option=com_fpbjrefusr&task=tokeninput_searchbudgetacc&q='+txtunit.value+'&typeacc=unit&fields=unitcode,description';";                                                                        
  $eventchange.="        params=params+'&swhere='+txtlocation.value;";                                                                       
  $eventchange.="    loadTokenInput2('txtunit',params,'Kode Unit', 60);";                                                                        
  $eventchange.="})";
```

so when that input type change, will call `onfocus` function to this input type and load token input result based query in  `tokeninput_searchbudgetacc`:

```
<input type=\"text\" id=\"txtunit\" style=\"width:60px;\" />
```

what i got is `txtlocation.value` still not changed where input type `txtlocation`

value changed by user. it caused the return value as `token list` from query will be fault (i used clause query).